# Is there something wrong with the way I'm making this request using Python Requests?

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to submit a simple post to an API, and it's telling me I'm missing fields.   The same data works when using a Chrome plugin to post.

Can you see anything wrong with the way I'm doing this?

```
def post(self, url, **kwargs):

        results = requests.post(
            self.host + url,
            params=json.dumps(kwargs),
            headers=self.headers)
        print "Original params: ", kwargs
        print "Ok?: ", results.ok
        print "Reason: ", results.reason
        print "JSON: ", results.json()
```

OUT:

```
Original params:  {'name': 'The Dants', 'id': 'Dant'}
Ok?:  False
Reason:  BAD REQUEST
JSON:  {u'id': [u'This field is required.'], u'name': [u'This field is required.']}
```

Comment: What it shows for `result.status` and `result.text`. To me it always helps playing first in iPython - using tab expansion I can call whatever method is available and changing the way I post is very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` puts the content in a query string.  You want to put your content in the body of the POST request.  It is possible to have both params and a body in a POST request, but that's not necessary here.

Change `params=` to `data=` to put your json in the body.